# live video streaming formats supported in iOS programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, video-streaming

I am working live video streaming in iPad app. I have done it previously using MPMediaPlayer with HTTP servers.

From link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432931/does-ios-support-anything-outside-of-http-live-streaming) I understand that "iOS devices support **HTTP** progressive download for .mp4 files, the server could be simply Apache or Nginx. The user experience is quite similar to HTTP live streaming , **RTSP** is also possible. You can migrate live555 to iOS platform as the RTSP client, as use DarwinStreamingServer as the RTSP server.

But my client has provided video streaming URLs in **UDP** (eg. udp://225.X.X.X:XXXXX ) format and also suggested to refer links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393371/ios-devices-not-receiving-udp-multicast-using-gdasyncudpsocket) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138272/gcdasyncudpsocket-and-multicast-sending-and-receiving) as support to his statement that this will work in iOS for live video streaming.

But I am unable to relate provided links by him with requirement. 
**My doubts are** -
what all formats does iOS supports for live video streaming ? 
Does this udp link is of use for me in iOS for video streaming ?

Answer (score 1):

On wifi, iOS supportS everything, because you have access to raw sockets, and the h.264 decode via VideoToolbox. So any protocol can be developed even If there is no out of box support. If you want the video to work over a cellular network, it MUST use HLS. no other options. (Unless you are Facebook, then apple will grant exceptions to this policy)